# Update string in file

Tags: php, file

I have a file with information like this:

```
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name  
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name 
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name  
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name  
    IP=127.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name 
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name  
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name 
    IP=121.0.0.1 Status=On Name=Name
```

How would I update the information in this file? E.g how would I update the row with the localhost IP set Status to Off and Name to test etc. What I tried is to locate the row I want to modify by IP address (in this case localhost - 127.0.0.1) then replace the value of Status= to Off with `str_replace()` etc. But when I try to change it back to On again it writes over another line/makes an empty line/adds more info.

Code I tried:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('user_info.wrd','r+');
while (!feof($file))
 {
  $str=fgets($file);
  if (strstr($str,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) 
    {
     $Status=substr($str,strpos($str,'Status=')+7);
     $Status=substr($Status,0,strpos($Status,' '));
     fseek($file,(ftell($file)-strlen($str)));
     $str=str_replace($Status,'Off',$str);
     echo $str;
     $str=trim($str);
     fwrite($file,$str);
     fclose($file);
     die;
    }
 }  
?>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the code as well.

Comment: ASCII file the extenstension '.wrd' is still text

Comment: First of all, the key to this if [`file()`](http://php.net/file) and `foreach`. Working with the file on a line-by-line basis if going to be much easier than all that `fseek()` nonsense. Secondly, that file is an nightmarish structure for this sort of operation - any chance you change the file format? Or better yet, use a database?

Comment: I thought of using a database but then i thought of how slow responses would be / lack of knowledge of mysql etc. But it's just something simple I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Nubcake A database will be *much* quicker than this flat-file approach. Believe me. What you want to do is quite simple in SQL, and there's no time like the present to start learning - you can always ask questions here if you can't work something out (once you had a go yourself, of course ;-))

Comment: OK i will attempt to use a database just 1 question what type does an IP address come under varchar etc. ?

Comment: I would set a field to store an IP address as a `VARCHAR(15)`, or possibly 4 separate integer columns depending on the application.

Comment: @Nubcake Remember, `Status` will be of type `BOOL` (or `TINYINT(1)`) and `Name` will be a `VARCHAR` of a length of your choosing.

Comment: If you like being thrifty, you can use [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) to store IPs into an INT field.

Comment: Well, people you are right, databases are much safer and easier to read&write datas than using filesystem I/O functions. But in cases where your webhosting not allows you to use a database, there using these file functions is the ok choice.

Comment: @Nubcake In php also sometimes occurs 'unknown' ip address, so probably better is to use the varchar.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my versions of the read_file and write_file functions (the code is not tested, but should work).

```
function read_file($filename) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
  $lines = explode((strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? "\r\n" : "\n"), $contents);
  $data = array();
  foreach($lines as $line) {
    $fields = explode(" ", $line);
    $ip_address = null;
    foreach($fields as $field) {
      $keyvaluepair = explode('=', $field);
      if ($keyvaluepair[0] === 'IP') {
        $ip_address = $keyvaluepair[1];
        $data[$ip_address] = array();
      } else {
        $data[$ip_address][$keyvaluepair[0]] = $keyvaluepair[1];
      }
    }
  }
  return $data;
}

function write_file($filename, $array) {
  $data = '';

  foreach($array as $ip_address => $flags) {
    $data .= "IP={$ip_address} Status={$flags['Status']} Name={$flags['Name']}";
    $data .= (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? "\r\n" : "\n");
  }

  file_put_contents($filename, $data);
}
```

Usage:

```
$data = read_file('filename');
$data['127.0.0.1']['Status'] = 'Off';
$data['127.0.0.1']['Name'] = 'My_Fancy_Name'; // note that spaces in the name are not allowed!
write_file('filename', $data);
```

Comment: Nice solution and even it can be simplified a bit :) @[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XrW3YN32)

Comment: Yeah, that's much simpler :) But maybe Nubcake needs the file format exactly like he has specified...We don't know :)

Comment: Yes stefreak, seems like he finally decided to use database, but imho this is good answer on his question, so no problem. Have a good day!